# Access iframe URL from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I've got an extension that needs to load up a page with lots of redirects in its background page. Once that page gets to a known URL (https://website.com/index.php), the iframe should have its `src` set to `about:blank`.

The final page is quite large and has big images and everything that don't need to be loaded, so rather than attach to the iframe's `onload` event, I set the following function on a 100ms interval:

```
function update(){
    if(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.location.href == "https://website.com/index.php"){
        console.log("Done!");
        clearInterval(updateInterval);
        document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = "about:blank";
    }
}
```

However, as soon as the iframe starts to load, update() throws this error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   https://website.com/index.php from frame with URL
>   chrome-extension://hdmnoclbamhajcoblymcnloeoedkhfon/background.html.
>   The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'chrome-extension', the
>   frame being accessed has a protocol of 'https'. Protocols must match.

I tried catch()ing that error, but the message passed back to Javascript unsurprisingly doesn't include the URL. The page redirects multiple times, so it's important to know the exact URL. The `src` property of the iframe also doesn't update to reflect redirects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After *lots* of Googling and nearly giving up, I came up with the following solution. It uses an injected content script to send a message back to the extension once the correct page has loaded.

manifest.json:

```
{
    ...
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    }, "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://website.com/index.php"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "*://*.website.com/*"
    ]
}
```

background.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="about:blank"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

background.js:

```
var waiting = false;

function login(){ // Call this function to start
    var frame = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    frame.src = "https://website.com/login/";
    waiting = true;
}

function callback(){ // This gets called once the page loads
    console.log("Done!");
}

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.loaded && waiting){
        // If you used a pattern, do extra checks here:
        // if(request.loaded == "https://website.com/index.php")
        document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = "about:blank";
        waiting = false;
        callback();
    }
});
```

content.js:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({loaded: window.location.href});
```